# Javascript: Get nth character of string (JSChallenger)

Tags: javascript

I am a total newbie and currently learning Javacript.
I encountered this problem on JSChallenger and have been struggling with it.
Here's my code:

```
// Write a function that takes a string (a) and a number (n) as argument
// Return the nth character of 'a'
function myFunction(a, n)
{let string = a;
let index = n;
return string.charAt(index);
}
```

Can anyone point out my errors?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Its working fine. I did not see any error in this code. Please refer this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/02gs5dby/

Comment: Seems to work just fine. What's the problem? (BTW you can skip creating two additional variables and just `return a[n]`)

Comment: it works fine but did you call the function? add this bellow your function myFunction(string, number);  and change the parameters to suit your case.

Comment: *"Can anyone point out my errors?"* What errors? What is telling you something is wrong? The site? If so, it's probably complaining about `string` and `index` -- they're completely unnecessary. Alternatively, it could be complaining about not handling multi-code-unit code points in the string (my blog post with details [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/)), but that's very unlikely. (If that were the problem, a solution to it would be `for (const ch of a) { if (n-- === 0) { return ch; } }` or alternatively `return [...a][n];`).

Comment: It's working fine. Just note that array index starts at 0. So n=0 will return first character.

Comment: well, the site reported that one or more test cases for my code failed so i could not pass. so im searching for something of a model answer. thanks all!

Answer (score 2):

Try this one

```
function myFunction(a, n){
return a[n - 1];}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a very short solution

```
function find( a, b){
return a[b]
}
console.log(find('how',1));
```

although you need to do some tests in the function to check if the input for b is greater than the length of a else it would fail.

You can do that like this

```
function find( a, b){
    if(a.length<b-1){
        return 'error';
    }
    return a[b]
}
console.log(find('how',5));
```

that way your code would be free from error

Answer (score 0):

```
// there is a shorter way to do this since you want to find what's missing here is what's missing. 
function myFunction(a, n){
    let string = a;
    let index = n-1;
    return string.charAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JS string's index starts enumerating from 0 so the n should be decremented by 1

```
// Write a function that takes a string (a) and a number (n) as argument
// Return the nth character of 'a'
function myFunction(a, n)
{
    let string = a;
    let index = n;
    return string.charAt(index-1);
}
```

the easiest way to write it would be:

```
// Write a function that takes a string (a) and a number (n) as argument
// Return the nth character of 'a'

function myFunction(a,n) {
   return a[n - 1];
}
```

Meaning return from string "a" of myFunction the index "[n-1]" , "n-1" it's a needed operation to get the right index because string index start enumerating from 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is very easy you can just return the **a[n]**
but it is not the right answer because as you know the strings in JavaScript are *zero-indexed* so the right answer is

```
function myFunction(a, n) {
    return a[n - 1]
}
```

Happy Coding & keep Learning

Answer (score 0):

also this solution works too, with empty space at first of string we can remove that counting from zero :

```
function myFunction(a, n) {   
   return ` ${a}}`[n]
}
```

but this is just **another** solution. not **tested**. and you can check this repo for other JSchallenger solutinos: [JSchallenger solutions](https://github.com/CyrusKabir/js-challenger)

Answer (score 0):

```
function myFunction(a, n) {
  return a.charAt(n - 1);
}
console.log(myFunction("hello", 2));
```

I think so this is best way

Answer (score 0):

in javascript, you can write this simple code to solve your problem
ex:

let string = "Hello";
let n = 2;

return string[n];

Comment: Please see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) on how to format code in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**that is a tricky question if you look to the test cases you will notice that it ignore counting from zero**

```
 function myFunction(a, n) {
   return a.charAt(n-1);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Method 1:

```
function myFunction(a, n){
  return a[n - 1];
}
```

Method :2

```
function getNthCharacter(a, n) {
  return a.charAt(n - 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the above question is

```
function myFunction(a, n) {
  return a[n-1]
}
```

Above can be solved as

```
    function myFunction(a, n) {
      return a.charAt(n-1)
    }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).